# Can I pass a variable of a type defined in my current module down to another module without having to redefine the same type?

Tags: fortran

I am defining a type in my module as following:

```
use my_other_module

type :: myType
  integer :: &
    a, b, c
end type myType

type(myType) :: myVariable
myVariable%a=1
myVariable%b=2
myVariable%c=3

my_other_module_function(myVariable)
```

With this structure, the compiler requires me to define `myType` in both my main and my other module. I can't import my main module in my other module because that would cause a circular import. How can I structure my program to solve this problem?

Comment: The term submodule is confusing - it means something very specific in modern Fortran (see e.g. https://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Submodules). As I understand it you are *not* in fact using submodules - but could you confirm this?

Comment: @IanBush yes you are right, I am using two entirely separate modules. I corrected the question accordingly.

Comment: You cannot declare the type twice, it is not guaranteed to work. They are two different types, even if named the same way. They are not guaranteed to be compatible, unless they are `sequence` or `bind(C)`. You would have to make another module and declare the type there. You can use the Fortran 2008 submodules to get rid of some need for the circular dependency, but that depends on the detailed structure of your code we cannot see. You would also have to show how the circular dependency arises, possibly in some subroutines or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derived type must be defined in the root `module`, and any other piece of code using it needs to reference it via the `use` statement.

In your case:

```
module my_other_module
  implicit none
  private

  public :: myType
  public :: my_other_module_function

  type :: myType
     integer :: &
       a, b, c
   end type myType

  contains

  subroutine my_other_module_function(myVariable)
    type(myType) :: myVariable
    print *, 'do something'
  end subroutine my_other_module_function
end module my_other_module

program test
  use my_other_module, only: my_other_module_function,myType
  type(myType) :: v

  v = myType(1,2,3)

  call my_other_module_function(v)

end program test
```

Note that you should avoid circular dependencies when calling modules, otherwise the dependency tree cannot be resolved. In other words, you cannot have this:

```
module m1
  use m2
end module

module m2
  use m1
end module
```

Comment: I see. In this case, what if I had my main program, the `my_other_module` module where `myType` is defined and another module that I would also like to pass a `myType` variable to? Would I then have to also use the `use my_other_module, only: myType` statement there as well?

Comment: Yes, you can always place your derived type in a root module that is referenced by several other modules down the dependency tree

Comment: Also note that the dependencies are resolved by your build system